# when building a project the customizable hook does not work correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing a project, I created a custom hook, using localhost, the project works correctly, it lists the information, however with the project built and sent to the cloud, the data does not return to me, as if the re-render did not work to launch the data from a .map on screen

Three files are being used to get this information:

- one containing a JSON with the list of requests,
- another containing the custom hook,
- and another containing the function call with a .map

```
// listRequest.js
export const listUrlGestaoQualidade = [
    {
        url: 'cadastro-liberacao-termofusaos',
        name: 'Pré - Qualificação de solda por Termorusão',
        qtd: 0,
        aprovado: 0,
        reprovado: 0,
        aproveitamento: 0
    },
];
```

```
// hooks
import { useCallback, useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalState } from "../store";
import { listUrlGestaoQualidade } from "../json/listRequests";
import api from "../services/api";

const tokenUser = localStorage.getItem('@app-token');
const licenca = localStorage.getItem('@app-licenca');
const projeto = localStorage.getItem('@projeto');

export const useGetQualidade = () => {

    const { setRegistersQualidade } = useContext(GlobalState);

    const executeGetQualidade = useCallback(async () => {

        const params = `?filters[licenca][$eq]=${licenca}&filters[numero_projeto][$eq]=${projeto}`;

        listUrlGestaoQualidade.forEach(async (request, index) => {
            await api.get(request.url + params, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenUser}` } })
                .then(res => {
                    if (request.name === 'Pré - Qualificação de solda por Termorusão') {
                        const statusAprovado = [];
                        const statusReprovado = [];

                        if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
                            res.data.data.forEach(status => {
                                if (status.attributes.status_deslocamento === 'Aprovado' && status.attributes.status_cisalhamento === 'Aprovado') {
                                    statusAprovado.push('Aprovado')
                                } else {
                                    statusReprovado.push('Reprovado')
                                }
                            });

                            listUrlGestaoQualidade[index].qtd = res.data.data.length;
                            listUrlGestaoQualidade[index].aprovado = statusAprovado.length;
                            listUrlGestaoQualidade[index].reprovado = statusReprovado.length;
                            listUrlGestaoQualidade[index].aproveitamento = (statusAprovado.length / res.data.data.length * 100).toFixed(2)
                        }
                    }
                }).catch(err => {

                });
        });
        console.log('listUrlGestaoQualidade', listUrlGestaoQualidade)
        setRegistersQualidade(listUrlGestaoQualidade)
    }, [setRegistersQualidade]);

    return { executeGetQualidade };
}
```

```
//  hook call containing .map
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { GlobalState } from '../../../store';
import { useGetQualidade } from '../../../hooks/useGetQualidade';
import { Container, Table, AreaRows, SessionTable, TitleSession, Title, AreaTable } from "./styles";

export default function Acompanhamento() {
    const { registersQualidade } = useContext(GlobalState);
    const { executeGetQualidade } = useGetQualidade();

    useEffect(() => {
        executeGetQualidade();
    }, [executeGetQualidade]);

    return (
        <Container>
            <Table>
                <AreaRows>
                    <td colSpan={9}>
                        <SessionTable>
                            <TitleSession>
                                <Title>Gestão de Qualidade e Ensaios de Campo</Title>
                            </TitleSession>
                            <AreaTable>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Descrição</th>
                                        <th>Quantidade</th>
                                        <th>Aprovado</th>
                                        <th>Reprovado</th>
                                        <th>Aproveitamento %</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    {registersQualidade.map(rows => (
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{rows.name}</td>
                                            <td>{rows.qtd}</td>
                                            <td>{rows.aprovado}</td>
                                            <td>{rows.reprovado}</td>
                                            <td>{rows.aproveitamento}%</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}

                                </table>
                            </AreaTable>
                        </SessionTable>
                    </td>
                </AreaRows>
            </Table>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

In localhost, it works correctly listing the information, but the build in the cloud does not list, guys if anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

It seems the re-render is not working, so I tried using the global state with useContext

Comment: did you checked browser Developer Tools? is request sent? is data received?

Comment: yes, even the data is listed in the console.log, and localhost works correctly, but the build does not

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your attention @skyboyer, in my case I needed to loop through each url of the array and make a request, but the `foreach` does not wait for each promise to be resolved, it passes directly without waiting, for that you must use `Promisse.all()`, or if you use `axios` `axios.all`

Comment: Hey, congratz on finding the answer to your question! The way it's written now, your answer is not very clear. It's never very readable to read a description of code. In this case, everyone would be better off if you show the actual code differences :) Don't hesitate to edit your answer and to show the differences in the code!

Answer (score 0):

here is the resolution of my problem, using Prommise.all which expects all promises to be resolved

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import api from '../services/api';

export const useGetLancamentos = () => {

    const [acumulado, setAcumulado] = useState([]);

    const executeGetAcumulados = useCallback(async () => {

        const tokenUser = localStorage.getItem('@app-token');
        const licenca = localStorage.getItem('@app-licenca');
        const projeto = localStorage.getItem('@projeto');
        const params = `?filters[licenca][$eq]=${licenca}&filters[numero_projeto][$eq]=${projeto}`;

        const endpoints = [
            'lancamento-geomembranas',
            'lancamento-geotextils',
            'lancamento-geogrelhas',
            'lancamento-gcls',
            'lancamento-geocelulas',
            'lancamento-geocompostos',
        ];

        Promise.all(endpoints.map((endpoint) => api.get(endpoint + params, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenUser}` } }))).then(allResponses => {
            console.log(allResponses);
            setAcumulado(allResponses);
        });
    }, []);


    return { executeGetAcumulados }
}
```